# Thinkpad X201 freezing on startup

Tags: windows-7, freeze, boot, thinkpad

I recently purchased a Lenovo Thinkpad X201 with Windows 7 x64. The computer arrived packed and new. We installed the most basic programs on it: Office 2010, Winrar and a printer.

After about a week, the computer started to freeze on startup. The events log showed nothing besides computer stopped for unknown reason. No minidump created.

Lenovo support claimed the issue is on the OS, so we restored the laptop to factory defaults. Two weeks later, the same issue again. Eventually, Lenovo support claimed they found an issue with the MB and a new laptop was sent to us.

The new laptop worked fine for 2 months. After which, the same issue start to show. Computer freezing on startup (after login) and sometimes mid-work. 
This time however, event log was logging errors.

First error we found was related to the Windows indexing service. Browsing the internet led to the `C:\windows\CSC` folder. Apparently there was no current owner. The problem disappeared for a week, and again returned. However, the CSC folder now had the current correct owner.

Event ID logs show:

```
ID - 141 
ID - 3036
ID - 59
ID - 100
ID - 55
```

I did a full offline `chkdsk /f` and a `sfc /scannow` which found no issues.